# Different Modularity Scores for community detection algorithms in R

Tags: r, networking, graph, modularity

Each algorithm gives a different **number** of modularity scores for community detection, and I am wondering why so.

Can anyone explain why are there always **4 modularity** scores for the `cluster_louvain()` algorithm in R?

```
lc <- cluster_louvain(g)
lc$modularity  #[1] 0.5963936 0.6443712 0.6488890 0.6490924
```

On the other hand, `cluster_infomap()` gives an **overall** modularity score.

```
imc <- cluster_infomap(g)
imc$modularity #[1] 0.584
```

And, the `cluster_fast_greedy()` gives 1 modularity score **per vertex**.

```
mba = cluster_fast_greedy(g)
summary(mba$modularity)

#Results
#      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
# -0.0000432  0.1842705  0.3540742  0.3332204  0.4643733  0.5288776
```